# Можно ли создать свой тип редактирования UITableView?

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios

Есть таблица **UITableView**: в *non-editing*-режиме она имеет пользовательские ячейки (*custom UITableViewCell*), в режиме редактирования требуется подставлять в начало ячейки мое изображение, а не стандартное. Стандартных, как видно [здесь](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1), 2: вставка и удаление. Мне они не подходят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно не пользоваться стандартным реактированием вообще, а сделать полностью свое редактирование такблицы. Ответ на этот вопрос есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/984) - то, что делается для мультиселекшена, дает возможность создать и свой тип редактирования.

Answer (score 0):

Ох, создавать кастомную таблицу - это еще тот геморрой и рак мозгов. Самый простой способ - это просто закинуть на каждую ячейку по кнопке `(UIButton)`, затем написать метод, который будет удалять из таблицы элементы, то есть удалять элементы из массива, и делать релоад таблицы. А отследить, какая кнопка была нажата можно через `[button tag]`.

**UPD:** Такой вариант работает более менее хорошо только в случае, когда `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` заменяется на `UITableViewCell *cell = nil`. В таком случае работает более корректно, а все потому что происходит своего рода "перекидывание" значения верхних тегов в нижние во время скролла таблицы. Извините, что кого-то ввел в заблуждение.