# Множественное выделение строк в UITableView

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios

Как реализовать multi-selection в UITableView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию, UITableView поддерживает режим выбора только одной строки. Но можно создать свой multi-selection в UITbaleView. Чтобы таблица имела возможность множественного выбора нужно поставить стиль стандартного выделения "none" и самостоятельно отслеживать события и менять вид элементов. Для этого следует выполнить несколько шагов:

1. Пусть на верхней панели таблицы есть кнопка "Edit", которая при переходе в edit-mode меняется на "Cancel". При переходе в режим редактирования снизу таблицы появляется панель инструментов с вариантами действий над элементами таблицы.
2. Для обнаружения выделенных строк использовать метод tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. В этом методе мы будем добавлять только что выбранный элемент в коллекцию. Т.к. мы не можем полагаться на стандартный UITableView, мы должны создать коллекцию, содержащую выделенные в данный момент элементы. Также, при выборе элемента мы должны сменить фон элемента и отодвинуть его от левого края, чтобы поместить туда специальный индикатор выделения (наподобие checkbox).
3. Панель инструментов нужно **создать** в методе viewDidLoad, добавив что-то подобное:

   ```
   actionToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 416, 320, 44)];
   actionButton =
       [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
           initWithTitle:@"No Action"
           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
           target:self
           action:@selector(noAction:)]
       autorelease];
   [actionToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:actionButton]];
   ```
4. Затем, в методе viewDidAppear мы можем **добавить** нашу панель инструментов в иерархию

   ```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [self.view.superview addSubview:actionToolbar];
   }
   ```
5. Стандартный режим редактирования для UITableView реализуется посредством вызова setEditing:animated:. Но т.к. Мы не собираемся использовать никакой из стандартных UITableViewCellEditingStyle, то вызов этого метода не является строго обязательным, но его можно будет использовать для уведомления UITableViewCell. Методы edit и cancel можно реализовать примерно так:

   ```
   - (void)edit:(id)sender {
       [self showActionToolbar:YES];
       UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton =
           [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
               initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
               target:self
               action:@selector(cancel:)]
           autorelease];
       [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:cancelButton animated:NO];
       [self updateSelectionCount];
       [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
   }

   - (void)cancel:(id)sender {
       [self showActionToolbar:NO];
       UIBarButtonItem *editButton =
           [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
               initWithTitle:@"Edit"
               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
               target:self
               action:@selector(edit:)]
           autorelease];
       [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:editButton animated:NO];
       NSInteger row = 0;
       for (MultiSelectCellController *cellController in
       [tableGroups objectAtIndex:0]) {
       [cellController clearSelectionForTableView:self.tableView
               indexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]];
       row++;
   }
   [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
   ```

   }
6. Далее, при вызове setEditing у UITableView таблица вызывает setEditing у всех видимых элементов (UITableViewCell). Мы можем переопределить этот метод и использовать для перехода из режима в режим отдельно взятого элемента таблицы (показать или скрыть "галочку"). Проще всего это реализовать следующим образом: конкретно в методе setEditing мы инициируем relayout методом setNeedsLayout, а основной код поместим в layoutSubviews (теперь мы будем правильно перерисовывать элемент вне зависимости от того, что стало причиной перерисовки).

   ```
   - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
       [self setNeedsLayout];
   }
   ```
7. Можно непосредственно в layoutSubviews и добавлять сам рисунок "галочки". Но с точки зрения организации кода это не очень красивое решение, т.к. подразумевается, что UITableViewCell - это только **макет** элемента. Поэтому лучше добавлять галочку уже в UITableView, но это неважно. Итак, в layoutSubviews мы будем отодвигать элемент от левого края, чтобы освободить место для "галочки", вот так:

   ```
   - (void)layoutSubviews {
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
       [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];     
       [super layoutSubviews];
       if (((UITableView *)self.superview).isEditing) {
           CGRect contentFrame = self.contentView.frame;
           contentFrame.origin.x = 40; // делаем отступ
           self.contentView.frame = contentFrame;
       } else {
           CGRect contentFrame = self.contentView.frame;
           contentFrame.origin.x = 0;
           self.contentView.frame = contentFrame;
       }
       [UIView commitAnimations];
   }
   ```
8. Теперь осталось только поставить

   ```
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
   ```

т.к. мы не хотим использовать стандартный selection. Вместо этого надо просто менять  backgroundView у элемента.

P.s. Пример можно посмотреть в приложении Mail.

Answer (score 2):

В iOS5 этот функционал встроен. Достаточно в `viewDidLoad` указать

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

[Пример кода от Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html).

П.С.: кстати, оригинал статьи, на которой основан ответ **CrazyWorld** находится тут: [Multiple row selection and editing in a UITableView](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html) (англ.)